# Automatic rmmod / modprobe based on dmesg parsing

Tags: debian, logs, kernel-modules, laptop, dmesg

I am using a MacBooPro10,1 Debian stable (default install with `rsyslogd`) system for which the trackpad eventually fails (pointer stop working) from time to time as can be seen :

```
$ dmesg
[...]
[1910159.662967] bcm5974: bad trackpad package, length: 8
```

The solution is trivial:

```
$ sudo rmmod bcm5974 && sudo modprobe bcm5974
```

But I'd rather have it being done automatically.

How can I parse `dmesg` output and trigger a command (`sudo` power) ?

Comment: Are you using `rsyslogd` for logging?

Comment: @meuh clarified

Answer (score 2):

You can ask `rsyslogd` to run a program when it matches the line. 
Create a file such as `/etc/rsyslog.d/my.conf` with a line like

```
:msg, contains, "bad trackpad package" ^/bin/mytrackpadreset
```

and this will run the script `/bin/mytrackpadreset` when the message is seen, passing the whole message as a single string argument. As the daemon runs as root, you can simply put the required `rmmod bcm5974 && modprobe bcm5974` command in the script, though you might need to set a suitable PATH first.

I think in the past `rsyslogd` would wait for the script to end before continuing, but this no longer seems to be the case. If you expect to see the message many times in a burst, you may need some extra work in the script to cope with being run several times in parallel.

This legacy format (`^program`) is superceded by the [omprog](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omprog.html) module which is more useful for programs you want to start once, and run continuously, passing messages to it on stdin.

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of `grep`-ing, you'll find the same information that `dmesg` output in `/var/log/messages`.

There remains the question of watching this file without wasting resources (and without a "one-minute `cron`", which is pretty inelegant)