# How can a bash script detect in real time when an ARM error occurs?

Tags: bash, syslog, temperature

How can a Linux bash script detect in real time when an error, such as Internal error: Oops: 37 [#1} ARM, occurs ? I'd rather my script not have to constantly scan system logs looking for such errors. Why do I want to do this ? I'm doing thermal stress tests on the cpu, and a sure sign of trouble is an oops message in syslog. I want my bash script, which is doing the thermal stressing of the cpu with the aid of a device to control the cpu temperature, to detect such errors in real time and log them along with its normal output so I can see which stress caused the error. I also see such error messages on the screen, but I have no idea how to catch them.

Comment: Are these kernel Oops messages, and if not where do they come from?

Comment: Can't you just put a header in each section of your script (eg. echo "Stress test #1", and then run your script redirecting to a logfile? (eg ./stress_test.sh > logfile)

Comment: Yes to the first response. I'm trying to capture in real time any error messages that the system sends so I can integrate it, and correlate it, in real time, with the log file that my test script creates. This way, I can see what test condition, i.e., what temperature, produced by my script and the custom heater it controls, that caused a system error. NOTE: These errors are usually attributed to a system software bug but there is ANOTHER cause -- heating of a PARTICULAR cpu chip, and this varies from chip to chip.

Comment: If you run rsyslogd you can have it match appropriate messages and cause it to run a program. see my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/519107/119298). Otherwise you can install abrt and have it call a hook when you get a kernel oops (I'm not sure if systemd hasnt taken over this function as well these days).

Comment: To @meuh: Great ! Thank you. It's MUCH more efficient than periodically grepping syslog for Oops:. As per your instructions, I made a file, /etc/rsyslog.d/oops.conf, with these contents: :msg,contains,"Oops: " /var/log/oops.log
and restarted syslog. Now each time there's an Oops:, this file gets updated. I can turn this into a real-time action in a script of mine by creating a script with inotifywait that looks for changes in that file.